Thank you, but please stop selectively upvoting my questions with a score of 9
Update: 601

What's the devil?
601?
The computer's overloaded - too much data coming in too fast!
Dividing and mutating at the same time?
And nothing to stop it. Normal Earth checks and balances don't exist for it.

The pattern has changed from questions with +9 to answers with +24


It seems someone sorted my questions by score and found the "nines" (score = 9) and has been upvoting them in groups of three or four at a time for the last week or so.
This is as far back as the little dropdown window goes.
While it's nice to think my posts are appreciated, the fact that they were selected for having a score of nine means these are not valid upvotes. The fact that they were done in small groups suggests someone is trying to fly under the wire - not be detected by the anomalous voting pattern detector.
Thanks, but please stop.
 

Four more just in the last few hours


It’s not just you. I have also noticed the same thing happen to my posts with 9 votes

By the way, I asked the user noted above about this. They replied rudely and noted that (due to necessity) my comment wasn't actually relevant to the post of theirs that it was on. After replying asking them to answer the question and reminding them to be nicer, they deleted their comment. Interesting.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The new auto text sounds really harsh for meta, but I do think this got a bit chatty even for here so I wanted to migrate it.

Relevant discussion: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/contributing-badges-by-up-voting-is-it-a-good-idea

@Starship how did you figure out the user who is upvoting? AFAIK, voting is anonymous.

@NilayGhosh So you can't see this now but at the time they were number in weekly votes with hundreds of sudden votes. How many votes you make it not anonymous. As well, every other user who had enough votes that week to account for the above (which is a small number) was a high-rep trusted user. As well, criedzhne has similar patterns of tons of votes in a short time without contributing anything to site on other stacks. Also a bit weird for them to reply rudely and then ignore the question if they didn't do it.
I don't know for certain, but that's why I suspect them. No magic (this time).
